# Whole Solution Complexity ... vs Development Complexity

Tags: python, ruby, deployment, complexity, lamp

I am generally a PHP Developer that deals in a few different MVC frameworks.  I am being tempted (like most) to break out of my comfortable LAMP environment in pursuit of a "prettier" and "more simple" language, attached to frameworks that are becoming more and more popular.

I agree with most arguments to switching to a (the) ruby framework or a python framework, and would trade out PHP for Python in the LAMP acronym any day of the week.

But as I've found in trying to get started with these, it's not quite that simple...

In my attempts to figure out the spaghetti of dependencies, versions, and install procedures, I've found that while final development time/simplicity is a benefit, in my mind it is almost overshadowed by the complexity of deployment...

Especially being use to the copy/paste deployment to the ever numerous lamp hosting services.

I am specifically speaking of

- Ruby on Rails
- Django (python)

To those that work in these platforms, was your initial experience similar? if so how did you overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

> To those that work in these platforms, was your initial experience similar?

No.

Django was quite simple.  Python is quite simple.

> spaghetti of dependencies, versions, and install procedures

You have to be much more specific about your experience. It was all pretty obvious from the Django documentation.

Comment: Sure, Hello world, and their little polling application was nice and easy, but as soon as you start introducing python package dependancies along with the whole "pip vs easy_install" thing, then I'm just thinking how the heck am I going to successfully deploy this thing, "mod_wsgi vs nginx vs lighttpd" etc.. just seems like their is less standardization which has led me to confusion to know what is the "right" way.

Comment: "python package dependencies" have never been a problem.  It's quite easy to manage.  For production, we actually use YaST on OpenSUSE.   "mod_wsgi vs nginx vs lighttpd"  seems like there is so much perfectly implemented  standardization that it barely matters what you choose -- Python and Django work with all of them equally well.

Comment: "have never been a problem. It's quite easy to manage." not my experience...  wish it was, love python syntax, but i don't think you can argue that managing python environments is as dead simple as a standard LAMP instance...

Comment: @jondavidjohn: Okay.  So you're saying that your overall question isn't really a question, but rather a complaint.  I always thought Python was the dead simple LAMP instance.  Your complaint is -- what -- that it's not PHP?  Is that the real point of the question?  To complain about Python and Ruby?

Comment: not at all, I'm searching for people who have had the same experience I have, that have overcome it.  This comment thread is turning more into my response to your answer which essentially boils down to " Django/Python is simple, RTFM" which I hope you can understand is not helpful.  I understand my question is vague, but I'm mainly looking for tips for someone coming from a LAMP copy/paste deployment environment.  Essentially things that you finally learned and said "Really wish I would have known this from the get go."

Comment: Also understand by problems are not with the languages, my it is the fact that I like them soooo much better than PHP that has me down this path.  My problem has been how you manage development/production environments for web applications.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: "Essentially things that you finally learned and said "Really wish I would have known this from the get go." There  aren't any.  It worked perfectly, exactly as documented.  I'll repeat my request, which you seem to be ignoring.   **You have to be much more specific about your experience**.  I can't imagine what problems you actually had, since I didn't have any.

Comment: ok, converted this to a more technical question over at SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883967/problems-getting-django-up-and-running-on-osx